# Trigger callback on dask.distributed.Variable.set

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I am working on a python app that requires data synchronization between a remote location (like on ec2) and a local location (like my laptop). Because some of the data involves very large arrays and I'm already using dask successfully in other places in the app, I'd like to use dask for this process.

I'm currently trying to use a `dask.distributed.Variable` to sync the data - either scattering the data first if it is an array - just setting it directly. I'm then able to run a `get` command to get the data, but what I'd really like to be possible is to connect a callback that will run on my local location whenever data is set on the remote location or visa-versa.

For example something like

```py
# On remote
from dask.distributed import LocalCluster, Client, Variable

cluster = LocalCluster()
client = Client(cluster)

# Define variable
aa = Variable('a')
```

```py
# On local
from dask.distributed import Client, Variable
client = Client(cluster.scheduler.address)

# Define variable
aa = Variable('a')

# Define my custom callback
def my_callback():
    print(aa.get())

# Do some connection magic ?????
```

and then if

```py
# On remote
aa.set(1)
```

Trigger my callback on my local.

Is such a paradigm possible here?

Comment: One thing I'm trying is the Pub / Sub model docs.dask.org/en/latest/futures.html#publish-subscribe but I'm still struggling to get it all working.

Comment: This has now been answered at https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/3188 using Pub / Sub, async and await